# How to bond two interfaces having different speeds in Linux?

Tags: linux, ethernet, bonding

I have successfully set up two simultaneous VPN tunnels over different Internet connections to the same server. Then I've bonded them using systemd-networkd and `balance-tlb` mode.

It works as designed, balancing traffic equally among the interfaces. However, the first one is much faster wired connection and another is an LTE connection. I would like to adjust (preferably dynamically) the share (percentage of traffic) between these two backing interfaces.

Systems at both ends are running modern Linux and the backing links are Ethernet connections.

How to adjust the percentage of traffic between these two interfaces?

Comment: No clue about this but I know that pfSense has some load balancing capabilities... you could even run it in a VM

Comment: The platform has to be Linux, although I'm interested if psSense does this internally and implement it on Linux if it is not yet supported yet.

Comment: It's a different flavor of Unix... it's an open source firewall based on FreeBSD... I've seen a lot of people talking about combining cable and 4G so there might be a good support community around it

Comment: Btw... what you're trying to do is called Multi-WANing.. it's a feature commonly left for routers to handle